# Not getting resize event

Tags: c, x11, xcb

First, make a list of the events that I want my window to receive, then I create my
window and after that I run in a while loop this event handler. My goal here is to print hello when the window is resized, and I don't understand why it doesn't. Here is the code :

```
uint32_t value_list[] = {
    XCB_NONE,
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS |
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY | XCB_EVENT_MASK_RESIZE_REDIRECT,
  };

  xcb_create_window(
    result->connection,
    XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
    result->window,
    screen->root,
    0, 0, width, height,
    0, XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
    screen->root_visual,
    XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK,
    value_list);
```

and

```
if(intern_window->event) {
    switch(intern_window->event->response_type & ~0x80) {
      case XCB_EXPOSE: {
        xcb_flush(intern_window->connection);
        break;
      }
      case XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE: {
        if( ((xcb_client_message_event_t*)intern_window->event)->data.data32[0] == intern_window->delete_reply->atom ) {
          intern_window->closing = true;
          free(intern_window->delete_reply);
        }
        break;
      }
      case XCB_RESIZE_REQUEST: {
        puts("Hello");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You want `XCB_EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY` (which you already have) and events `XCB_CONFIGURE_NOTIFY` (which you don't have). resize requests are something else. Still, in your setup, you should be getting resize requests. Do the other cases (expose and client message) work? See https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.2.4

Answer (score 1):

```c
uint32_t value_list[] = {
    XCB_NONE,
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS |
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY | XCB_EVENT_MASK_RESIZE_REDIRECT,
  };

  xcb_create_window(
    result->connection,
    XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
    result->window,
    screen->root,
    0, 0, width, height,
    0, XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
    screen->root_visual,
    XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK,
    value_list);
```

So, `value_list[0]` is `XCB_NONE` and `value_list[1]` is the event mask you want. You then use just `XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK`, thus `value_list[0]` is your event mask and `value_list[1]` is ignored.

You are not getting the events since you did not ask for them.